# Symfony in a subfolder 404 Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a project made with Symfony and i've a little issue, let me explain !

I have my back office on this URL : https://domain.tld/platform

My website is accessible but i have this error :

```
Oops! An Error Occurred

The server returned a "404 Not Found".

Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
```

I don't know why i've this message, maybe Symfony try to get files from https://domain.tld/ instead https://domain.tld/platform

So How can i say to my htaccess to use the entire URL Base, https://domain.tld/platform and not only https://domain.tld ?

Here, my .HTACCESS

My web server is Apache.

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# startpage (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewritting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the startpage because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # The following rewrites all other queries to the front controller. The
    # condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual
    # hosting, the base path will be prepended to allow proper resolution of the
    # app.php file; it will work in non-aliased environments as well, providing
    # a safe, one-size fits all solution.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the startpage to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Apache Configuration

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}


Timeout 300


KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5


User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all denied
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

And website apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:5009>
    ServerName subdomain.domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM eboraas/apache-php:latest

COPY ./ /var/www/html

COPY ./extra/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY ./extra/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
COPY ./extra/ports.conf /etc/apache2/ports.conf
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl -y
RUN curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN apt-get install php5-gd -y
RUN apt-get install nano -y
RUN apt-get install git-core -y
RUN cd /var/www/html && chown -R www-data:www-data .
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/app/cache/prod
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/app/cache/dev
RUN service apache2 restart
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN service apache2 reload; exit 0
EXPOSE 5009
```

Symfony error :

```
request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotAcceptableHttpException: "No matching accepted Response format could be determined" at /var/www/html/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/FOS/RestBundle/EventListener/FormatListener.php line 63 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotAcceptableHttpException: No matching accepted Response format could be determined at /var/www/html/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/FOS/RestBundle/EventListener/FormatListener.php:63)"} []
"} []  eption:  at /var/www/html/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:823
```

Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Comment: Symfony should work just fine in any subdirectory - maybe you should append your apache config aswell.

Comment: @ccKep Yeah you right! It's added!

Comment: What's the directoy of your symfony installation?

Comment: @ccKep in /var/www/html

Comment: So your app.php is in `/var/www/html/web/app.php` or `/var/www/html/symfony/web/app.php` or where? Which version of apache are you using?

Comment: @ccKep my app.php is in /var/www/html/web/app.php

Comment: And you are opening your page using `http://subdomain.domain.tld:5009/` ? Did you reload the apache config after adding the vhost / making the changes? What does the access/error log print?

Comment: @ccKep No, it's override by AWS ! With EC2 ! Yes, i will add my dockerfile configuration, maybe it can help you to help me aha! The access to apachelog is /var/log/apache2/project_error.log or log symfony?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never used AWS - I suppose the logs (apache access/error log & symfony log) could give more hints - maybe turn up the logging level temporarly while you're testing (or use app_dev.php for the time being).

Comment: @Clowning Did you enable `mod_rewrite` ?

Comment: You should clean the cache. Try `rm -rf app/cache/*` or try to access app_dev.php front controller

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev Yes it's enable!

Comment: @ste I've already do that :/ !